# Generic class Inheritance issue

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have the following situation:

```
class MyControl<T> : UserControl where T:TClass
{
    public T Field {}
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs<T>> MyEvent;
}
class DerControl1 : MyControl<ClassA> {}
class DerControl2 : MyControl<ClassB> {}
```

How I should implement inheritance to have a base class for DerControl1, DerControl2 to have access to interface of MyControl?

```
SomeBaseClass control = condition ? DerControl1 :DerControl2;
control.Field = null;
control.Enabled=false;
```

What class should SomeBaseClass be?

Comment: You need to make `T Field` ->  `object field` or have DerControl's implement an interface and have `IDerControl Field` instead.

Comment: Meirion Hughes, that's not a good idea,because I should cast Object to my class every time

Comment: Change class MyControl<T> to interface IMyControl<T>. Change class to interface.

Answer (score 2):

Define another, non-generic interface `IMyControl` and implement it explicitly:

```
public interface IMyControl
{
    public TClass Field { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

class MyControl<T> : UserControl, IMyControl where T:TClass
{
    public T Field { get; set; }
    TClass IMyControl.Field
    {
        get { return this.Field; }
        set { this.Field = (T)value; }
    }
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs<T>> MyEvent;
}
```

You can now cast your derived controls to `IMyControl` and access the `Field` property as a type `TClass`. Trying to return as anything else violates [co/contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) (you can return an `object` but it is preferable in this case to return a `TClass` since the type constraint already exists)

Comment: Consider this: `IMyControl c = new MyControl<ClassA>(); c.Field = new ClassB();` This will compile, but unless `ClassB` derives from `ClassA`, it will throw an exception at runtime on `(T)value` line.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that is a natural consequence of what the OP wants to achieve. The same is true of the `IList` interface in .NET

Comment: @AlexG Not quite: `IList` in .NET has that same problem due to historic reasons and backward compatibility requirements. Designing something like this into a new system is a different thing. I disagree that this is a *natural* consequence of what the OP wants to achieve: it lets him achieve what he wants, but it's far from being natural :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserControl` to access the `Enabled` field, but there is no common type that defines `Field`. You cannot put `Field` in a common non-generic interface, because its type is generic.

Starting with C# 4.0, you can use `dynamic` for things like that:

```
dynamic control = condition ? DerControl1 :DerControl2;
control.Field = null;
control.Enabled=false;
```

This may be slightly slower, but it will compile and do what you want.

Comment: no no, please  do not use dynamic everywhere it is easy and invitingly but there are special OOD instruments for this purposes, generics is enough

Comment: @sll "generics is enough". That's not so in this specific case (please prove me wrong).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: this "specific case" is a consequence of a bad design. Using of `dynamic` here just hides a problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this can be done by explicit interface implementation as per my answer

Comment: @Dennis I wouldn't be so eager criticizing someone else's design by looking at ten lines of his code.

Comment: @AlexG Your solution pushes a serious limitation into a class design, letting one bypass generics by using the common interface, essentially nullifying the compile-time benefit of using generics in the first place.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - far preferable to the use of `dynamic`, essentially nullifying the compile-time benefit of **type safety**.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight,is there any solution?

Comment: @user2170491 Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh =)  and how should I implement Event?

Comment: @AlexG Using `dynamic` nullifies type safety in this one specific statement, local to the code that uses `dynamic`. Using a non-generic interface creates a hole through which anybody using `MyControl<T>` will be able to bypass generics - anywhere, in anyone's code.

Comment: I'll be honest, dynamic (in my opinion) should only ever be used for arithmetic on unknown value types, with an implicit understanding that the unknown value will always implement said operators. Anything else will be a living nightmare for future (other) developers to bug hunt.

Comment: @MeirionHughes Although I do agree that one should be careful when using `dynamic`, I would refrain from putting too much restriction on their use: they are nowhere near as evil as one may think. For what its worth, I think that too much static type safety is grossly overrated: I would rather use `dynamic` than jump through too many hoops to stay statically typed. For example, I would prefer `dynamic` to adding an otherwise unwarranted interface. After all, pythons and objective Cs of the world all have learned to live without static typing pretty comfortably :)

Answer (score 0):

The use case is unclear.
If this code:

```
control.Field = null;
control.Enabled=false;
```

won't be placed into a generic method (or into a method of a generic type), than you don't need generic at all:

```
class MyControl : UserControl where T:TClass
{
    public object Field {}
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
}
```

Otherwise, this code will work just fine.

Comment: no, it is widely used in another code, this code sample is just a special case

Answer (score 0):

Using your own question, couldn't you just use an interface?

```
public interface IMyControl<T> where T:class
{
    T Field { get; set;}
    event EventHandler<MyEventArgs<T>> MyEvent;
}

public class MyControl<T> : UserControl, IMyControl<T> where T:class
{
    public T Field { get; set;}
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs<T>> MyEvent;       
}
```

And then to use :

```
// (which equates to IMyControl control = ...)
var control = condition ? new MyControl<ClassA>() : new MyControl<ClassB>();
control.Field = null;
control.Enabled = false;
```

This saves you having multiple classes for each Type parameter you want to use and therefore encourages code reuse and follows polymorphism (OOP).

Hope that is helpful!

**EDIT**

OK - so Alex was right and I shouldn't have fired from the hip on that one!  After a bit of investigation this seems to be a lot harder than I thought!  So I began to wonder if what you're asking is the right way to go.  Now, whether it is the sort of answer you want or not, I don't know, but here it is for you to ponder.

Basically, donn't use generics.  It makes life really really difficult in this scenario!  Instead, hide behind interfaces.  The code below achieves the same as you're trying to above, but with the exception that you now have field tied to a 'concrete' interface.  But realistically, you want this - you should have known behaviours and patterns, otherwise, to my mind, you don't know what your system should be doing and therefore there's something wrong with your requirements.  Anyway, surmon over, here's some code!

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    int I { get; set; }
    string S { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyControl
{
    IMyClass Field { get; set; }
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
}

public class MyControl : UserControl, IMyControl
{
    public MyControl(IMyClass field)
    {
        this.Field = field;
    }

    public IMyClass Field { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
}

public class MyClass1 : IMyClass
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am a MyClass1!!!";
    }
}

public class MyClass2 : IMyClass
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am a MyClass2!!!";
    }
}

var control = someCondition ? new MyControl(new MyClass1()) : new MyControl(new MyClass2());
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling this? Type inference on the ternary statement will fail.